# jQuery - How to create animation that moving between two table cells?

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate, cell

Just found on w3schools an example on how to create animation:

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $("div").animate({left:'250px'});
});
```

I am trying to figure out how based on this example I can make an animation that moving between two table cells, is it even possible? couldn't find any clue for it.

Comment: I was trying to make a formula that will convert a cell number to left and top css parameters, and then I would create the animation like in the example above. But It's not working, the static things on the table are not shown the right way once the animation is starting.
Maybe I need canvas for another layer?

Answer (score 0):

And you tried with remove and add to the other cell?

Ex:

```
  <tr>
    <td id="cell1">
    <div id="div1"></div>
    </td>
    <td id="cell2">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <script>
  $("button").click(function(){
  $("#div1").animate({left:'250px'});
  $('#div1').clone().attr('id', 'celltmp').appendTo('#cell2');
  $( "#div1" ).remove();
  });
  </script>
```

you needs polish this, but it's an idea :p